# ascending sort of a singly linked list

Tags: c, list, linked-list

i'm working on this program that sorts a list. but the problem is that the element in head will be  ignored in the second recursive call. es:

```
input: 7->1->8->0->NULL OUTPUT: 1->0->7->8->NULL.
```

why is the `1` ignored?

this is the node struct:

```
struct nodo {
    int elem;
    struct nodo *next;
};
```

and function:

```
struct nodo *ordinaLista(struct nodo *head) {
    //in ordine crescente

    if (!head)
        return NULL;
    else {
        if ((head->next) && (head->elem >= head->next->elem)) {
            int tmp = head->elem;
            head->elem = head->next->elem;
            head->next->elem = tmp;
        }
        //printList(head);
        
        head->next = ordinaLista(head->next); 
        head->next = ordinaLista(head->next);
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: This is not a valid sort algorithm. After running this, the head element can only be one of the two first elements in the original list. Even if this was a valid algorithm, it runs in exponential time. Switch to a known algorithm such as merge sort, selection sort, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function does not sort the list properly: you only sort the first 2 elements and proceed to sort the rest of the list: the only element guaranteed to end up in the proper position is the greatest one that will become the last element.

Calling the function recursively twice may solve the problem, but you need to change the order of operations: for a simplistic implementation with exponential complexity **O(n!)**, you should first sort the rest of the list, then test if the first element needs swapping with the second element, ensuring that the first element is the smallest one, finally if the elements were swapped, re-sort the rest of the list.

Here is a modified version:

```
struct nodo *ordinaLista(struct nodo *head) {
    //in ordine crescente

    if (head && head->next) {
        head->next = ordinaLista(head->next); 
        if (head->elem > head->next->elem) {
            int tmp = head->elem;
            head->elem = head->next->elem;
            head->next->elem = tmp;
            head->next = ordinaLista(head->next);
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

This approach is very inefficient, but seems to correspond to the code you submitted in the question. Much more efficient approches are available to sort a linked list, such as mergesort.

Comment: This has exponential complexity.

Comment: @interjay: indeed it does... answer amended.

Comment: This is the best solution without changing my initial "logic". It works. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Let's simulate the sort procedure:

7->1->8->0->NULL

1->7->8->0->NULL

In fact, it is enough to simulate the first step. As you can see, the "1" node is swapped to the first position, and then the program continues to execute backwards, and "1" is ignored. In fact, your sorting algorithm is not correct. Your sorting algorithm is actually a "bubble". To complete the sorting, multiple bubbling is required. For the specific algorithm, you can refer to "bubble sort".

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your function is that you don't really perform a sort. Your function just swaps the value of the integer with the next one if it's greater.

This way, on a single iteration you are guaranteed that the last item in the list is the largest.

Why are you calling the function recursively twice? This action seems weird to me.

*PS: avoid code comments in Italian, English is always preferable*

Answer (score 0):

OP's sorting code is broken

Rather than minor fixes to this inherently slow approach, consider a more efficient one.

Example:

```
// Pseudo code
struct nodo *ordinaLista(struct nodo *head) {
  // Walk list to find length N                     O(n)
  // Allocate N `elem` array A[]                    O(1)
  // Walk list and assign A[]                       O(n)
  // Sort array: qsort(A)                           O(n * log(n))
  // Walk list & re-assign list elements from A[]   O(n)
  // Free A[]                                       O(1)
}
```

Comment: @chqrlie I was trying not to _hog_ all the attention.

Comment: OK, now this is getting boar-ing.